# Remotely IE11 not working - Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, internet-explorer-11

I'm facing problems with IE11 on a remote node. when I run a test,It is only open the page and stop functioning after that, I have did the following

- Protected mode settings are the same for all zones
- Enhanced Protected Mode is disabled
- In the registry, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0
- ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION
- ENABLE_ELEMENT_CACHE_CLEANUP

**BUT that did not solve the problem**

any advice?

**P.S**

> Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true,
>   elementScrollBehavior=0, ignoreZoomSetting=true,
>   enablePersistentHover=false, ie.ensureCleanSession=true,
>   browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true,
>   unexpectedAlertBehaviour=accept, version=11,
>   ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=true,
>   cssSelectorsEnabled=true, requireWindowFocus=true, initialBrowserUrl=,
>   handlesAlerts=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true,
>   browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=,
>   takesScreenshot=true}]

**Code**

```
String Node = "http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:5558/wd/hub";
DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
cap.setCapability("ie.ensureCleanSession", true);
cap.setBrowserName("iexplore");
cap.setPlatform(org.openqa.selenium.Platform.WINDOWS);
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION,true);
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.ENABLE_ELEMENT_CACHE_CLEANUP,true);
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IGNORE_ZOOM_SETTING,true);
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOR,"accept");
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS,true);
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INITIAL_BROWSER_URL,"");
cap.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.SILENT,true);
driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(Node), cap);
```

Comment: What exception does it throw? I've written a page with some [throubleshooting tips for Selenium and IE Driver](https://github.com/seleniumQuery/seleniumQuery/wiki/seleniumQuery-and-IE-Driver) - they are useful for selenium by itself too. If you get around your problem, then maybe posting an answer here (yourself, it's OK) should be nice too.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to find element on closed window (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Does the IE even open?

Comment: Yes it does and allow me for on click only after that it not taking any actions .. even I can't end and close the browser (I tried  close() & quit())

Comment: Did you try to run using that "introduce flakiness..." option? Also, it appears you did, but can you confirm you added the `FEATURE_BFCACHE` registry in your windows? Did you correctly add for your windows version?

Comment: @SarahQA Can you provide the code of how you are instantiating the driver?

Comment: @acdcjunior  Yes I did Please check the code above

Comment: @Saifur  I add the code above

Answer (score 0):

Do you have windows update KB3025390 Installed?

If so this will explain why the IEDriver is not working correctly.

If you uninstall that update it will work correctly, this seems to be an issue the Selenium guys are aware of. I am not sure on the progress of this issue.

Comment: I double check for that update but I didn't find it. I think it's not installed

Answer (score 0):

I just need to but some link in the initial driver `INITIAL_BROWSER_URL,""` like www.google.com   `INITIAL_BROWSER_URL,"https://www.google.com"`..I'm not sure why  but it is the only way to make it work.